# Is it possible to make a link "active" (with outline) when it is reached by links?

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to make the active outline appear when an anchor is reached by link (just like it does when tabbed to).

I am able to select and update the target anchor's css color using jquery, but not change it's state to active.

Here is the html & jquery code and a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/_StephenC/Ea9GZ/

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#four" id="one" tabindex="1">Uno</a></li>
<li><a href="#four" id="two" tabindex="2">Dos</a></li>
<li><a href="#one" id="three" tabindex="3">Tres</a></li>
<li><a href="#two" id="four" tabindex="4">Quatro</a></li>
<li><a href="#three" id="five" tabindex="5">Cinco</a></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").click(function(event) {
var mylink = $(this).attr('href');
alert(mylink);
$(mylink).css('color','red');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think .focus() is what you look for. From your the jsfiddle link, just add $(mylink).focus(); to you code.

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
            var mylink = $(this).attr('href');
            alert(mylink);
            $(mylink).css('color','red');   
            $(mylink).focus();
        });
```

Is that what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 2):

Use following code,

```
$(mylink).focus();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ea9GZ/19/

Comment: Thanks, that was Andrew's suggestion, too. Works in Chrome & Explorer but not FF.

Comment: I saw Andrew's first and accepted before checking the time. sorry about that!